# How to deal with SSDT `refactorlog` merge conflicts?

Tags: git, refactoring, git-merge, sql-server-data-tools, refactoring-databases

We have two feature branches that both made changes to the database schema in an SSDT project. Feature #2 was merged into `master` after Feature #1 and has a conflict on the `refactorlog` file.

Is it possible to identify how the refactorlog should be merged manually, by inspecting the changes? Given my understand of how the refactorlog works it seems as if this would be highly likely to fail during deployment to a production-like environment.

How do we manually merge conflicting schema changes using SSDT without the likelihood of deployment failures or data loss?

Answer (score 1):

I've been manually fixing merge conflicts in the .refactorlog file for quite some time now for the same scenario. I can't seem to figure out a way to get git-merge to be able to handle the changes unless I stay in a single branch forever. That file is just an XML file, you would think it could handle that type of file.

I personally use Sourcetree with Bitbucket Cloud and Beyond Compare as my diff tool so fixing merge conflicts isn't too difficult once you begin to understand the layout of the .refactorlog file.

I don't think there is an answer to this problem. I've conceded to the fact that if source control for multiple branches is a must then fixing merge conflicts for this particular file is part of the deal.

For what it's worth, I've done many, many changes to my databases' schemas in both test and production without any issues thus far once I fix the conflicts.